# PhoneGap framework error - application has stopped

Tags: cordova

I am using PhoneGap framework (version 1.3.0). I installed Eclipse and Android SDK Plugin (New Version 4.0).

When I run my application everything is okay (sample program), but then I receive this message:

> unfortunately your phonegap application has stopped.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You probably didn't copy plugins.xml into your res/xml directory in
your project.

Comment: What exactly is the error message you got?

Comment: error msg is : "unfortunately application name has stopped?"

Comment: nithin can you explain in full details pls

Comment: nithin plugins.xml is xml file name right but i copied my xml file in res folder but already there in assests/www/my xml file name. pls can you explain in full details

Answer (score 0):

Rename your lib folder to libs and update your build config with new path.
Clean and build..